# Output Radio Circuit Board to Speaker

Tags: audio

I have a AM/FM radio board I found and am trying get playing through a small speaker.  The other components were missing so I don't know how this connects to the rest of the system which had a CD player, tape deck and the like.

The board has a single set of input wires pictured below.[image: IO Wiring]

The on board chip is a [Toshiba TA8167N](http://pdf.dzsc.com/TA8/TA8167N.pdf) which I have found runs on 3 volts and have managed to power.  Now I am trying to figure out what is required to connect to the speaker.

As there is only a single out for L and R which connect to the 'R-Out' and 'L-Out' pins on the chip I'm not sure how to complete the circuit.  From reading around it looks like I need an 'R-Ret' and 'L-Ret' respectively to complete it but there is no wiring for this available.

I think SL connects to the Stereo LED but I can't follow the MO or MU to the chip as the connections sit under the tuning wheel.

EDIT:

PCB picture added.

[image]

Comment: A radio has an RF aerial input. L, R, Mo (Mono), and Mu (multiplex) are all outputs. Ther's no evidence here that you need any more components, but if you do, a closeup of a PCB isn't sufficient to answer the question. You need to provide a schematic.

Comment: I've looked for a schematic.  Board Number is 13011-514-810 but with no success which is why I posted the link to the micro controller as it was all I had.  Maybe my question was phrased poorly. As I have a single wire out for say the left speaker I'm not sure how this works going to a speaker where I require both positive and negative wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Toshiba TA8167N](http://pdf.dzsc.com/TA8/TA8167N.pdf) has single-ended outputs -- the return for *both* L and R outputs is the GND pin of the chip (pin 9).
Is pin 9 connected to the "-" pin of the connector you showed?

Tuner chips like these are rarely connected directly to a speaker.
More typically, the tuner chip output pin is connected through a 4.7 uF capacitor (as shown on p. 8 of the TA8167N datasheet) to a "volume knob" connected to an audio amplifier such as the
[Texas Instruments LM386N-4](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/lm386-453073.pdf), as shown on p. 6 of the LM386N-4 datasheet.

The LM386N-4 and many other audio amplifiers are also single-ended -- the return is the GND pin of the chip.
You'll need 2 such audio amplifiers (or a "dual amplifier"), one to amplify the L signal and the other to amplify the R signal.

(Could you show a photo of the entire PCB? Perhaps your PCB already includes a volume knob and perhaps even an amplifier).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have added the full PCB.  The volume knob was definitely elsewhere.

Comment: Also, pin 9 is connected to the '-' pin of the connector